# How can I get rid of the 'keeps stopping' notification which destroys subsequent UI tests in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, ui-automation, android-espresso

I have running some UI tests, and when 1 fails, other ones will also fail because this annoying notification is shown:

[image]

Ofcourse I can add additional logic to check if this dialog is open, but sometimes it opens a few seconds after the other test is already running.

How can I make sure this notification is never shown for my app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android Test Orchestrator to run each of your tests within its own invocation. Crashes are also isolated.

https://developer.android.com/training/testing/instrumented-tests/androidx-test-libraries/runner#use-android